# Filter list of dictionaries if at least x keys have empty value

Tags: python

I am trying to filter a list of dictionaries based on the number of keys with empty values (for empty value I would like to consider empty strings '' and empty lists []).

for example

```
list_products=[{'index':1, 'type':'house', 'price': '', 'bar': []},{'index':1, 'type':'house', 'price': 'expensive', 'bar': ['yes','big']}]
```

I need to eliminate the first dictionary of the list (number of keys with value is 2 or less). The actual dictionary has many more keys and I would prefer a solution where I do not need to specify the key in an if statement to check for its value...

is it possible to have something like that...

```
 list_products=[d for d in list_products if len(d.values())<2]
```

It does not work beacuse an empty list is not seen as empty by python... any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are `''` and `[]` the only "empty values," or do you also accept the other values that Python considers false (`False`, `0`, `None`, `{}`, `set()`, `()`, etc.)?

Comment: If you say "An empty list is not seen as empty" then I think `d.values()` does not return what you think it returns.  Check `list_products[0].values()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something like

```
[d for d in list_products if sum(bool(v) for v in d.values()) > 2]
```

explanation: you can `sum` boolean values: `True` coerces to one.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
treshold = 2
for item in list_products:
    non_empty = 0
    for key in item:
        if item[key] not in ('', []):
            non_empty += 1
    if non_empty > treshold:
        result.append(item)
```

Here you just set your treshold and get what you want in `result` list.